# Sending base64 UIImages comes out empty

Tags: html, uiimage, base64, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I'm trying to send an HTML email with embedded UIImages.

This is my code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailComposer setSubject:NSLocalizedString(@"Subject", @"Default Subject")];

    // Build email body (HTML)
    UIImage *emailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(emailImage)];
    NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedString];
    NSMutableString *emailBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<HTML>Hey,<br><br>Here's the image!"];
    [emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'></html>",base64String]];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
    [delegate.viewController presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
```

When the Email Modal View Controller comes up I see the images just fine. But when I tried to view this email on my Mac and on my iPhone and the images comes out empty.

Comment: yes - I saved the data as files and then sent the files

Comment: I have the same problems with you like this "But when I tried to view this email on my Mac and on my iPhone and the images comes out empty"

Comment: did you try to save them? how are you attaching them to the email?

Comment: i used this code to make the logo of my email :     [emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'></html>",base64String]];